# phpunit get exception message

Tags: php, cakephp, exception, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I've just started with php unit. 
In my test cases UsersController should return:

```
public function UsersController() {
    ....
    throw new \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException();
}
```

phpunit code

```
$this->setExpectedException('Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException');
```

returns an assertion failed that looks like:

> App\Test\TestCase\Controller\UsersControllerTest::testActivate
>   Failed asserting that exception of type "Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException" is thrown.

Meanwhile browser return a 404 PageNotFound and `$this->assertResponseOk()` returns:

> App\Test\TestCase\Controller\UsersControllerTest::testActivate
>   exception 'Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException' with message 'Not Found' in /vagrant/ifmx.local/src/Controller/UsersController.php:215

Does somebody know why it's happened? And is there any way to get exception message in unit test.

Comment: `return throw`? That's a parser error right there...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood how the integration test case works.

It doesn't just wrap a call to a controller method, like `$controller->action()`, it simulates a whole request, and as such, exceptions are being catched, and result in error pages being rendered, just like it happens when you are visiting a URL in your browser.

So PHPUnit will never know about the exception, and thus you cannot use the expected exception feature as you would when directly testing specific code parts where exceptions bubble up to PHPUnit. If that would happen, then it wouldn't be possible to assert responses, which one might want to do, even when an exception has been thrown.

Possible exceptions are being buffered in the [**`IntegrationTestCase::$_exception`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.TestSuite.IntegrationTestCase.html#$_exception) property, which you can for example use to test if, what kind of exception has been thrown, etc, like

```
$this->assertInstanceOf('\Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException', $this->_exception);
$this->assertEquals('Not Found', $this->_exception->getMessage());
```

Comment: Yes, You are right. I've tried to use TestCases not correctly. 
Thanks a lot